# Fetching twitter feed into IOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, twitter

I'm trying to fetch twitter feeds of a certain user into my IOS app. First I got it working with this link.

```
https://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/wwwkrcgenkbe.json?count=25&from=wwwkrcgenkbe
```

But when I tested it I got the following error:

```
{

    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Sorry, that page does not exist",
            "code": 34
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twitter recently switched off that API endpoint. (`https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#11716`)

You need to be using URLs with the format `api.twitter.com/v1.1/`.

I suggest reading the latest API documentation, this will probably be a good place to start: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: I've checked it but I don't know how to build up my url. Do you maybe have an example url?

Comment: Looking at the example on the URL I linked I would assume something like this: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2 However, this fails in its raw form. I believe this is because you now have to send oAuth data for any request for the 1.1 API. I haven't done all the reading required for this myself so I can't help you any more than this I'm afraid.